# symbolic file reading partial data

Tags: amazon-athena

I have saved monthly data in a given S3 bucket and can run athena query without any problem. But if I use symbolic file, athena is reading only January and July data. This is very strange.

My symbolic file looks something like this...

```
s3://some_bucket/sub_bucket/no_details_201801.csv.gz
s3://some_bucket/sub_bucket/no_details_201802.csv.gz
s3://some_bucket/sub_bucket/no_details_201803.csv.gz
s3://some_bucket/sub_bucket/no_details_201804.csv.gz
s3://some_bucket/sub_bucket/no_details_201805.csv.gz
s3://some_bucket/sub_bucket/no_details_201806.csv.gz
s3://some_bucket/sub_bucket/no_details_201807.csv.gz
s3://some_bucket/sub_bucket/no_details_201808.csv.gz
s3://some_bucket/sub_bucket/no_details_201808.csv.gz
s3://some_bucket/sub_bucket/no_details_201810.csv.gz
s3://some_bucket/sub_bucket/no_details_201811.csv.gz
s3://some_bucket/sub_bucket/no_details_201812.csv.gz
```

Out of these 12 files, 2 months data files are missing and athena is not complaining about it. That is nice. But it is not reading the rest 10 files. That is OK. But it seems to be reading only 2 files (randomly selected) that is not acceptable.
Has anyone experienced this with athena symbolic file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using the `SymlinkTextInputFormat`. If any of the files are missing in the symlink file, both Athena and Presto on EMR should fail the query. I I was not able to reproduce the issue.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `symlink_test`(
  `col1` string, 
  `col2` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'escapeChar'='\\', 
  'quoteChar'='`', 
  'separatorChar'=',') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.SymlinkTextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://my-bucket/datasets/symlink'
```

If any of the files in the symlink does not exist, Athena and Presto gives an error message similar to:

```
HIVE_UNKNOWN_ERROR: Input path does not exist:[...]
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I was pointing to a different symbolic file. I should have double checked before asking.